# Is there an existing SqlConnection that I can use in LinqPad?

Tags: linqpad

I am trying to test out some [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) stuff using LinqPad.

Dapper needs a SqlConnection (IDbConnection really) to work.  I could construct my own in the code window, but I thought if LinqPad already had made one, I would just use that.

Does LinqPad have a SqlConnection object already hanging around that I could use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
this.Connection
```

It's a `DataContext`, after all.

Comment: I had tried it, but not hard enough.  I needed to open it for it to work.

Comment: The connection should already be open in current versions of LINQPad.